# block users by country in .htaccess

Tags: security, htaccess

Is there a way to block users from a particular region. Currently I have compiled a list of over 100 IP addresses that I block in my .htaccess file. Unfortunately as the list grows I see a great number of offenders come for the same areas, like China. Can I block that entire country? Or region?

Comment: Are you really prepared to firewall off a billion people because of 100 bad apples?

Comment: Yep! They are not a part of my market but a few rotten tomatoes spoil the experience for my community here. And I'd like to add to it Korea too.

Comment: Isn't this taking the naughty & nice thing a little bit too far? :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When you site with thousands of members goes blank for a few hours -- is it time to be nice?

Answer (score 3):

Use [GeoMax lite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) to identify the country and block them. 
[mod_geoip apache module](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip) can help you in what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in the .htaccess file:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
Country: China
ISO Code: CN
allow from all
</Limit>
```